# jquerymobile panel cross page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

jquerymobile panel cross page
I wanna make a same panel menu for every page.
because the panel menu is the same content for every page.
How do I do? or any suggest?
My sample code is by following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="status">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
   <h1>Access Point Status</h1>
   <a class="ui-btn" data-rel="back" style="background:none;">back</a>
   <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-right" style="background:none;" href="#left-menu">menu</a>
  </div>
  <div id="left-menu" data-role="panel" data-position="left">
   <a class="ui-btn" href="#status">STATUS</a>
   <a class="ui-btn" href="#A">A</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" data-theme="e">
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" id="A">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
   <h1>PAGE A</h1>
   <a class="ui-btn " data-rel="back" style="background:none;">back</a>
   <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-right" style="background:none;" href="#left-a">menu</a>
  </div>
  <div id="left-a" data-role="panel" data-position="left">
   <a class="ui-btn" href="#status">STATUS</a>
   <a class="ui-btn" href="#A">A</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" data-theme="e">
     </div>
 </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry about my less information, actually I wanna the effect as I added the sample code. page#status, and page#A use the same panel menu and follow the effect.

Answer (score 0):

create a panel in body tag and outside page div like following

```
<body>
<div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="overlay" data-position="right" data-theme="b">
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li data-icon="false">
        <a href="#" data-transition="pop" data-rel="close">
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li data-icon="false">
        <a href="#login"data-rel="close">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
..... page ....
</div>
....  other pages ....
</body>
```

then in pagecreate event of first page add this

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#firstPage", function () {
    $("body>[data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin(); //you can put this in document.ready but its not preferable 
}
```